# Почему не работает метод wall.get?

Tags: вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Я хочу использовать этот метод для получения списка публикаций с группы. Если я его использую без параметров - он работает, но если я добавлю параметр `filter= suggests` (предложенные записи) - ничего не выводится. Хотя записи есть. Официальная документация гласит, что для этого метода не нужен `access_token`. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: может, filter= suggests без пробела нужно? =)

>>filter=suggests

Comment: извините, опечатка

Comment: вот пример `https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=-77524071&filter=suggests&v=5.28`. говорит, что ничего нету, а на самом деле есть

Comment: @Diefair, подозреваю, что для этого действия (конкретно с suggests) токен все-таки нужен, а строчка в доке относится к общему характеру выполнения.

Comment: делал и с токеном, тот же результат((

Comment: извиняюсь, с токеном заработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации есть неточность. Сам столкнулся. Это касается прав у пользователя, от которого происходит отображение. Для этого фильтра обязательно передавать access_token — написано [здесь](http://vk.com/dev/wall.get):

```
suggests — предложенные записи на стене сообщества (доступно только при вызове с передачей access_token);
postponed — отложенные записи (доступно только при вызове с передачей access_token);
```